# InfiniteLine Woes

Tags: graphics, version-10

I am puzzled that the `InfiniteLine` below intersects with only one of the two points.

```
Graphics[{PointSize[.04], Point[a = {6, 17}], Point[b = {7, 37}],
  InfiniteLine[a, b]},
 Axes -> True,
 GridLines -> {{a[[1]], b[[1]]}, {a[[2]], b[[2]]}},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 40}},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: line]

Any ideas about what is going on?  BTW, I am using Mathematica 10.0.2.0

Comment: Take a closer look at syntax ;) You need `InfiniteLine[{a, b}]`.

Comment: What about this? (from the documentation) `Graphics[InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], Frame -> True]`

Comment: What what about this? There are two possible forms: `?? InfiniteLine`. p.s {0,0} is quite special in this contex.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I think that's in fact a bad example in the documentation; that's a line "in the direction of {1,1}" which also happens to pass through {1,1}. It may have been clearer if they had chosen a different first point, e.g. `Graphics[InfiniteLine[{1, 0}, {1, 1}]`

Comment: @MarcoB,  That's just what tripped me up. And I was in an unusual hurry too.

Answer (score 4):

```
Graphics[{PointSize[.04], Point[a = {6, 17}], Point[b = {7, 37}], 
  InfiniteLine[{a, b}]}, Axes -> True, 
 GridLines -> {{a[[1]], b[[1]]}, {a[[2]], b[[2]]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 40}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

From the documentation:

> InfiniteLine[{Subscript[p, 1],Subscript[p, 2]}] represents the infinite straight line passing through the points Subscript[p, 1] and Subscript[p, 2]. 
>       InfiniteLine[p,v] represents the infinite straight line passing through the point p in the direction v.  >>

Comment: Thanks.  The syntax even matches that of `Line`.  I'm surprised I didn't try it.